# List changed after SharedPreferences.commit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I've made a simple application with a recyclerview in a fragment. In `OnCreateView` I get a list from SharedPreferences (from a separate class), then I save it into a private list like this:

```
mModel = AnotherClass.GetListFromSharedPreferences();
```

The problem is when I try to add an element to the RecyclerView (and in SharedPreferences) by clicking a button. This is my code when the button is pressed:

```
AnotherClass.saveInSharedPreferences(itemAdded);
mModel.add(ItemAdded);
```

`saveInSharedPreferences` get the saved list from SharedPreferences:

```
 public boolean saveInSharedPreferences(@NonNull final Item item) {
    List<item> currentSaved = GetListFromSharedPreferences();
    if (currentSaved.size() == 0) {
        currentSaved = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    currentSaved.add(item);
    mCache = currentSaved ;
    return save();
}
```

And it calls the save method, that save the list edited in SharedPreferences:

```
  private boolean save() {
    if (mCache != null) {
        try {
            final JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for (Item item : mCache) {
                JSONObject item = item.toJson(); //Just put everthing in a JSON Object
                array.put(item);
            }
            final String arrayAsString = array.toString();
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(KEY, arrayAsString).apply();
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works correctly(it adds the new item in SharedPreferences), but after the calling of this methods, seems like that my mModel already has the new Item added! Before calling `mModel.add`. 
Since OnCreateView is called just 1 time when I call the fragment, and the mModel is valorized only in that time, I don't see how is possible that my mModel is modified just after I edit my SharedPreferences...?

Comment: Add more code. Code added isn't much to go by.

Comment: Added the only 2 methods called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to listen to newly added items  use registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  it will keep called when items added

use it on onCreateView

```
SharedPreference.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener (SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener)
```

Comment: But I just don't understand why my list mModel is changed after these instructions...

Comment: I think mModel reference shared with recyclerAdapter dataListArray.

Comment: I think you're right, mModel change if I change the SharedPreferences,  changed from

mModel = AnotherClass.GetListFromSharedPreferences();

To 

mModel =  new LinkedList<>(AnotherClass.GetListFromSharedPreferences());

And it works, thank you